# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have setup Python, Django and MySQL on my Windows machine.  I'm trying to verify my database connection by running the following from a directory named 'zibit':

```
> myvenv\Scripts\activate
> set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
> django-admin dbshell
```

After running the last command I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'
```

I tried updating my wsgi.py file to the following after seeing some related posts online:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

import sys
path = 'C:\Users\abc123\Documents\zibit'
sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
zibit
|
+--mysite
|  |
|  +--settings.py
|
+--myvenv
```

I feel like I'm missing something very simple.  Any ideas?

EDIT:

I've updated the path to:

```
path = r'C:\Users\abc123\Documents\zibit'
```

Unfortunately, I still seem to be getting the same error.  This is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\abc123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\abc123\Documents\zibit\myvenv\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\abc123\documents\zibit\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\abc123\documents\zibit\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "c:\users\abc123\documents\zibit\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\users\abc123\documents\zibit\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "c:\users\abc123\documents\zibit\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\abc123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'
```

Comment: Normally you would run `python manage.py dbshell` instead of using `django-admin`, and the `manage.py` will take care of setting the path for you.

Comment: I was under the impression I needed to set it myself.  Seems to be working as you described.  Much appreciated!

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-and-manage-py) on `django-admin` and `manage.py` - they say that it's usually easier to use `manage.py` once you've created the project.

Answer (score 0):

The back-slashes are killing your path string:

```
path = 'C:\Users\abc123\Documents\zibit'
```

should be

```
path = r'C:\Users\abc123\Documents\zibit'
```

or

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\abc123\\Documents\\zibit'
```

If you're using `virtualenvwrapper-win` you could go to the zibit directory and issue

```
add2virtualenv .
```

which will set up the paths for you (it will work better than editing the wsgi file if you need to work with multiple virtualenvs).

Comment: I was hoping that was it.  Unfortunately I'm still seeing the error.  I updated my post with the full error I get.

Comment: are you missing an `__init__.py` file next to `settings.py`?

Comment: Just double-checked and I see that file in the sam directory.  I have the following files within the mysite directory: __init__.py, settings.py, wsgi.py, urls.py and another folder named __pycache__

Comment: Based on Alasdair's comment my understanding is that the path is automatically set if I run "python manage.py dbshell" instead of using "django-admin dbshell".  That seems to be working, so I'll stick with that for now.  Thanks for the help!